# BottomNavigationView overlaps the last item of RecycleView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have two cases. Both with bug.

1. Root element is `ConstraintLayout`. `Fragment` element with `NavHostFragment` (`RecycleView` inside). `BottomNavigationView` connect to `bottom`. **Bug:** doesn't work animation of scrolling by `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
2. Root element is `CoordinatorLayout`. The animation by `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is work. **Bug:** `BottomNavigationView` covers last item of `RecycleView`.

Two gifs. Attention the AppBar and date 5 August 2019 (in the bottom).

Please help to fix the layout so that the last element is not covering `BottomNavigationView` and working AppBar animation.

[image][image]

**First case**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frame"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            style="@style/ToolbarTextAppearanceStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?mainBackgroundColor"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_botton_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Second case**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frame"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            style="@style/ToolbarTextAppearanceStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main" />
    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?mainBackgroundColor"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_botton_navigation" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Use second case and add bottom padding to `RecyclerView` equal to bottom bar height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `RecyclerView` one of the next:

```
<!-- android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height" -->
android:paddingBottom="150dp" 
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

[image][image]